# How to run this code in list

Tags: python, file, list, integer

I had written the code given below: 
Its output datatype is integers, I want these integers to be in list. I'm new to python. Please suggest how to do it.

```
lineNo = 0
css = open("/Users/john/Work/html/Ribbon/header.css")  
for line in css.readlines():
    lineNo = lineNo + 1
    if "width" in line:
        print(lineNo)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lineNo = []
css = open("/path/to/stylesheet.css")  
for i,line in enumerate(css.readlines(), start=1):
        if "width" in line:
            print (i, line)
            lineNo.append(i)


print (lineNo)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). `enumerate` gives you the line number with each line, starting at `1` in this case. No need for `.readlines()` since iterating though a file-like goes through each line.

```
[line_no for line_no, line in enumerate(css,1) if "width" in line]
```

Comment: @aix I didn't know either until I saw someone do it on this site :)

Answer (score 1):

Using your original code you only need to add two new lines:

```
lineNo = 0
css = open("/Users/john/Work/html/Ribbon/header.css")  
myList = []  # create an empty list
for line in css.readlines():
    lineNo = lineNo + 1
    if "width" in line:
        print(lineNo)
        myList.append(lineNo)  # add your item to the list
```

Once you feel more comfortable with Python you might consider [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) in combination with [enumerate](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate) to get the line count automatically in place of the original approach. See @jamylak's solution for the use of those constructs.

In the meantime, here's an [informal introduction to lists](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) and the Python [docs on lists](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html).

Comment: +1 I borrowed your link, hope you don't mind :D This is a good way of doing it with the original code but list comprehensions make it trivial.

Comment: @jamylak no problem, and I agree, I would use list comprehension myself too, but seeing that the OP is new to Python he might be more comfortable with a more conventional approach that shows the basic use of a list before a more Python specific approach.

Comment: NameError: name 'lineNo' is not defined

Comment: Ooops, I left off the first line of your code `lineNo = 0` when I copied your solution. I added it now, thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @Levon and you're still doing it using a variable, the OP said he needs to use a "list".

Comment: @Nimbuz I don't understand your comment, maybe you can elaborate? Every
solution here is using variables, I don't see where the OP says not to use variables (?) - Instead the OP said "**I want these integers
to be in list**", this solution puts these integers into a list. My
solution was geared toward someone who said he was new to Python, so
deliberately simple. I also referred the OP to both `enumerate` and `list
comprehension` once he was more comfortable with Python, but my goal was to present a solution most suitable to
the user's level, not to show off my Python skills :)

Answer (score 0):

```
def extractWidth(line):
    return line  # your code here

def loadWidths(path):
    with open(path) as f:
        return [extractWidth(line) for line in f if ("width in line")]

loadWidths("/Users/john/Work/html/Ribbon/header.css")
```